# In Java, can 'this' be ever null inside the constructor?

Tags: java

While the object is being constructed, can it be null ?

```
class Sample {
  public Sample() {
      if( this != null ) { // Is this check necessary anywhere in the constructor?
        this.doSomething();
      }
  }
 ....
 ....
}
```

Comment: Who voted this question for no apparent reason down? (+1 again ... but still on -1)-

Comment: @Angel: I'm mostly guessing, but it could have to do with the fact that it's not consistent. For example it doesn't explain what *exactly* the title has to do with the question.

Comment: Guess I should have put the description in the title and the tile as an example in the description :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` won't be null - but if you call a non-final instance method from a constructor, you should document that really thoroughly, as any subclass constructors *won't* have been run yet. That means if `doSomething()` is overridden in a subclass, it will see the default values for any fields declared in that subclass (where the default is the default value for the type, *not* whatever the variable initializer might show). Basically it's worth trying to avoid calling non-final instance methods in constructors if at all possible.

Comment: I'd do `s/virtual/non-final, non-private, non-static/`. "virtual" isn't really a common term in Java-land.

Comment: I suppose there is a risk that this answer cannot be full understandable to Krishnaraj

Comment: It makes sense however to call a factory method which is redefined in a subclass to return an also redefined Object.

Comment: @Angel: it can make sense, but it needs to be documented!

Comment: Ofc it should be documented, otherwise no one would know about the easy way of providing his own factory method ;D

Comment: @Joachim: Edited, although I wish it would *become* more common :)

Answer (score 3):

No, `this` can't ever be `null` in a constructor in Java.

In fact `this` can't ever be `null` in Java. Anywhere.

At any given point in Java you are either in an object context and have access to a non-`null` `this`, or you are in a static context and can't access `this` at all, but it can never be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` reference is never `null` in Java, also not in the constructor. However, it's normally not a good idea to call non-final methods that might have been overridden in subclasses from the constructor, because the subclass-part of the object will not yet have been initialized.

An example:

```
class Superclass {
    public Superclass() {
        // NOTE: This will print null instead of "Jack", because the subclass constructor has not yet been run!
        printName();
    }

    public void printName() {
        System.out.println("Superclass method");
    }
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass {
    private final String name;

    public Subclass() {
        name = "Jack";
    }

    @Override
    public void printName() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Subclass();
    }
}
```

Comment: ...So, does the problem occurs when you call new Subclass() in the main()?

Comment: @MatX Yes. You can copy and paste the code, compile it and try it out for yourself.